# Why can't we return a mysqli object directly from a function? The object must be stored in a variable first?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm reading a book about PHP, and having a problem with this example:

```
<?php
function dbConnect() {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'learnphp';
    $user = 'phplearner';
    $pwd = 'wxyz1234';
    return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Can't open database");
}
$conn = dbConnect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM images';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
?>
<p>A total of <?php echo $numRows; ?> records were found.</p>
```

It doesn't run in my local server (XAMPP 1.8.1; PHP 5.4.7; mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026; MySQL 5.5.27) - with this error message:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   **D:\xampp\htdocs\learnphp\mysql\mysqli.php** on line **11**

However, when I changed this line:

```
    return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Can't open database");
```

to:

```
    $mysqliobj = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Can't open database");
    return $mysqliobj;
```

It works normally:

> A total of 8 records were found.

Why can't I use `return new mysqli(...)` like the example? Is this a new coding requirement for PHP 5.4+ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[..] or die()` construct leads to funny behaviour in conjunction with the return statement: The whole thing is interpreted as a boolean expression.

And because `new mysqli` will never be false, the "die" is never processed, and thus, your function returns `true` instead of a newly created instance of `mysqli`.

EDIT:

If you still would like to use `or die()`, do this:

```
$result = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) ;
if (!$result) die ("Can't open database.");
return $result;
```

Comment: I removed the `or die(..)` and it works! From the example, what should we use instead of `or die(..)`?

Comment: @weeix The reason for this behavior is the *operator precedence*. `=` is evaluated before `or`, but `return` is evaluated after both. So `$foo = $bar or die()`. Results in the same boolean `true` value for the expression overall, but as part of that operation `$bar` has been assigned to `$foo` and nobody cares about the expression value here.

Answer (score 0):

change this...

```
return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Can't open database");
```

to this..

```
return mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Can't open database");
```

Comment: I actually stumble to this kind of error. I just quit using query() and proceed to use mysqli_query().